# Create C++ array of unknown type

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, alignment, c++20

Is there some way to create an array in C++ where we don't know the type, but we do know it's size and alignmnent requirements?

Let's say we have a template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T* create_array(size_t numElements) { return new T[numElements]; }
```

This works because each element `T` has known size and alignment, which is known at compile-time. But I'm looking for something where we can delegate the creation for later by simply extracting size and align and passing them on. This is the interface that I seek:

```cpp
// my_header.hpp

// "internal" helper function, implementation in source file!
void* _create_array(size_t s, size_t a, size_t n);

template<typename T>
T* create_array(size_t numElements) {
    return (T*)_create_array(sizeof(T), alignof(T), numElements);
}
```

Can we implement this in a source file?:

```cpp
#include "my_header.hpp"

void* _create_array(size_t s, size_t a, size_t n) {
    // ... ?
}
```

###### Requirements:

- Each array element must have the correct alignment.
- The total array size must be equal to s*n, and be aligned to a.
- Type safety is assumed to be managed by the templated interface.
- Indexing into the array should use correct size and align offsets.

I'm using C++20, so newer features may also be considered.
In advance, thank you!

Comment: You could create an array using [`std::aligned_storage::type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) as the element type, and then [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) your actual objects onto those array elements afterwards as needed. Except that the size and alignment values for `aligned_storage` need to be template parameters, not runtime function parameter. Hmm...

Comment: Looks uncannily like `std::vector` ...

Comment: Honestly, the more times I read this, the more I'm certain that (1) your *actual* design problem could benefit from some application of type erasure  (2) [you are fixated on a solution to the actual problem, so you ask about that instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/317773).

Comment: Yeah, I think is called `std::vector`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you could do exactly what you described with [`aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc), no compile-time type required.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have already tried `std::aligned_storage` together with placement new syntax, and that is an almost perfect solution. I just wanted to know if I could do better. But `aligned_alloc` seems like it could be the solution - would you see any problems with using that for creating an array?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica perhaps you are right. I have a pool allocator that I want to "de-templatize", for more than 1 reason. At this point I simply want to understand the possibilities, and then experiment seeing if they could work my case. Furthermore, I might want to delegate the memory block from an application-managed (larger) allocation. That is my _actual_ design problem, but I just thought that too specific for a short online query. :)

Comment: As far the second point you think about, have you seen [`<memory_resource>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory_resource)? It's the library spec and support for polymorphic allocators. You might be able to draw up some inspiration there.

Answer (score 1):

While you can also implement this yourself, you can simply use `std::allocator`:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T* create_array(size_t numElements) {
    std::allocator<T> a;
    return std::allocator_traits<decltype(a)>::allocate(a, numElements);
}
```

and then

```
template<typename T>
constexpr void destroy_array(T* ptr) noexcept {
    std::allocator<T> a;
    std::allocator_traits<decltype(a)>::deallocate(a, ptr);
}
```

The benefit over doing it yourself via a call to `operator new` is that this will also be usable in constant expression evaluation.

You then need to create objects in the returned storage via placement-new, `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::construct` or `std::construct_at`.

Anyway, first make sure that you really need to do all of this memory management manually. Standard library containers already offer similar functionality, e.g. `std::vector` has a `.reserve` member function to reserve memory in which objects can be placed later via `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `resize`, etc.

---

If you want to implement the above yourself, you basically need

```
#include<new>

//...

void* create_array(size_t s, size_t a, size_t n) {
    // CAREFUL: check here that `s*n` does not overflow! Potential for vulnerabilities!
    return ::operator new(s*n, std::align_val_t{a});
}

void destroy_array(void* ptr, size_t a) noexcept {
    ::operator delete(ptr, std::align_val_t{a});
}
```

(Note that identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace scope and may not be used there as function names, so I changed the name.)

Comment: I thank you for the suggestion, though I was looking for a non-generic solution which strips away any kind of template. It looks like `decltype(a)` is still dependent upon a template. And yes, I'm building custom allocators, and I'm simply researching and trying to educate myself in the possibilites. Being able to implement everything in a source file (not a header) would be a huge bonus for me. If that's not entirely possible that's okay.

Comment: @alexpanter See my edit, but I don't really see how this helps you in any way. There is basically no cost to having the allocation templated on the type and you need to cast to the target type somewhere anyway.

Comment: Yeah the cast away from void* is my main headache. This is a difficult problem, and in time I will figure out a good solution. But there are costs involved with allocation on the templated type, including code size and compilation times, both of which are a concern to me. If I'm not wrong that is.
Part of the learning process is figuring out the correct questions to ask. You were very helpful!

Comment: @alexpanter It is very likely that the `allocate` calls from `std::allocator` will be inlined everywhere anyway, so that in the end there will only be calls to `::operator new` one way or another and no additional code. These calls can't be inlined because they are globally replaceable by the user. If you put `create_array` in a `.cpp` instead of a header it can't be inlined without LTO, so you will very likely have another function call indirection that isn't really needed. (The exception to this is probably the overflow check in `std::allocator` which might increase code at the call site.)

Comment: Good point! I will need to rely on LTO anyway, since I need the possibility of delegating memory blocks to sub-allocators. So I can't guarantee that all allocations will be using `new`. And great that you pointed out the overflow risk - I will definitely have both `s` and `a` be U32, and the product of them U64.